# Changing json values has no effect using boost C++

Tags: c++, json, boost, edit, savechanges

I am trying to change some values in my json file but it has no effect in the json file even though it prints the changes I have made below.

### The json file:

```
{
"schemaVersion":1,
"array":[  
  { //values...
  },
  { //the relevant values..
    "id":"stackoverflow",
    "visible":true,
  }
 ]
}
```

The json file is valid I just wrote the relevant things.

### Boost code:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree doc;
string test = dir_path.string();
boost::property_tree::read_json(test, doc);

BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& framePair2, doc.get_child("array")){
   if (!framePair2.second.get<std::string>("id").compare("stackoverflow")){
        cout << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("id") << endl;
        cout << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("visible") << endl;
        framePair2.second.put<string>("visible", "false");
        cout << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("visible") << endl;
   }
```

### The output:

```
stackoverflow //which is fine
true          //which is also fine
false         //which is exactly what I changed and need
```

### The problem:

There are no changes in the json file **even** though it prints a success change via `framePair2.second.put<string>("visible", "false");` and I don't understand why.

How can it be that it prints `false` **after** i use *put* method and in the json file it is still `true` ? Do I need to save the json file ? if so, what is the command for it using boost ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: JSON is not a file (it's a data representation). And a property tree is not JSON (it's a native C++ datastructure representing hierarchical data). These differences are subtle to an end user, but vital to programmers because they allow us to work with the abstracted concepts independently of the implementation. When you set a value, you don't care whether the JSON ends up in a memory mapped file or getting digested as a SharedKeySignature for a REST-ful logon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

- Boost's json parser only use string in the ptree, meaning there is no reference for the ptree to types such as bool/int. ONLY string.
- Although I used not so elegant solution such as normal file manipulation using the ifstream and ofstream classes, [here](http://www.json.org/) you can find (scroll down to C/C++ section) all the json API's that support types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to save the JSON file.

There's no "command" for this. Instead use a *function* just like you used one (`read_json`) to read it:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/json_parser/write_json_idp202532560.html

**Update**

Here's a sample (reading from a string, writing to std::cout). I fixed an error dealing with array elements that don't have the `"id"` property.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ae6b2cc1264bf03)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

std::string const sample = R"(
    {
        "schemaVersion": 1,
            "array": [{
            },
            {
                "id": "stackoverflow",
                "visible": true
            }]
    }
)";

int main() {

    ptree doc;
    std::istringstream iss(sample);
    read_json(iss, doc);

    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type & framePair2, doc.get_child("array")) {
        auto id = framePair2.second.get_optional<std::string>("id");
        if (id && !id->compare("stackoverflow")) {
            std::cout << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("id")      << std::endl;
            std::cout << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("visible") << std::endl;
            framePair2.second.put<std::string>("visible", "false");
            std::cout  << framePair2.second.get<std::string>("visible") << std::endl;
        }
    }

    write_json(std::cout, doc);
}
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow
true
false
{
    "schemaVersion": "1",
    "array": [
        "",
        {
            "id": "stackoverflow",
            "visible": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey sehe,
So I just need to write: boost::property_tree::read_json(test, doc); (again...) and I am done ?

Comment: No. You should read the linked documentation. It's pretty much the same, but **not** the function name :)

Comment: And yes, computers will require you to tell it what it should do. That's not "again...". That's _be precise_. And the reason is that your assumptions make sense to you, but not to everyone (imagine reading from a network socket. How would you "magically" save any changes back onto the original source?)

Comment: Yes, @OhadM, I can give you an example. But no, since you asked within 1 minute of me posting the answer (which _linked_ the documentation) and again withing seconds of me commenting the explanation, I'm going to allow you some time to understand the documentation.

Comment: Thank you sehe, I will look it over on Sunday.

Comment: sehe, it's working but when I save the file: overwrites it or print it as in your example I lose all the types (via boost website: "....all type information is lost...."). As you can see in your example you print false but when you write_json you get "false".
Any idea how can I save the json file as is ? (Serialization ?)

Thank you.
P.S: I also tried framePair2.second.put<bool>("active", true); but with no sucess

Comment: @OhadM If you want JSON, maybe you should be using a JSON parser instead? [just a sample](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/q27967677/test.cpp)... There are good JSON libraries around

Comment: Is that your API ? I have just downloaded [json spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented). Which should I use ?

Comment: @OhadM You should use what you prefer. At work I use (an improved version of) the parser you you just saw. Mostly in automated serialization code (so user friendliness is not a goal). Thing is, Boost Property tree is not a XML/JSON/Whatever library. It is a PropertyTree library (Whatever the hell that is. I admit I think Boost PropertyTree doesn't need be in Boost. It's applicability appears to be mimimal)

Comment: Downloaded both of your files json.hpp and json.cpp. Added the .hpp to the 'header files' folder in my project and json.cpp to the 'sources files' folder. I am getting can't include json.hpp. any ideas ?

Comment: @OhadM that would be an elementary project configuration task. There are a dozen ways in which this is usually done. And they're all pretty easily researched. Also: I'm not prepared to give support on that library. It's provided as-is. If including the file gives you trouble, I'd tend to suggest that you want an easier-to-use library that might e.g. even have documentation.